# Sylius layout override

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am not able to override sylius default layout. I add file `layout.html.twig` to `/app/Resources/Frontend/` and nothing happen. Can you someone help me please?

Comment: Don't add answers in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try `/app/Resources/SyliusWebBundle/views/Frontend/`